# ¿Cómo posiciono los iconos de font-awesome con CSS3?

Tags: css3, font-awesome

¿Cómo puedo posicionar los iconos de font awesome indicando izquierda, derecha, abajo o arriba con CSS3?

Este es mi código:

```css
    *, *::after, *::before{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body header{
     font-family: Open Sans;
     background: #363636;
    }
    body header .contenedor{
     max-width: 1000px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       display: block;
    }
    header .logo{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    header .logo h3{
     color: #f3f2f1;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 40px;
     font-family: 'Oswald', arial;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    header .menu{
     position: absolute;
     top: 12px;
     display: flex;
     align-content: flex-end;
    }
    header .menu i{
     color: #f3f2f1;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    header .navegacion{
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: block;
     max-width: 1300px;
    }
    header .navegacion_hijo{
     position: absolute;
     background: #363636;
     padding: 40px;
    }
    .navegacion_hijo ul li{
     list-style: none;
     padding-top: 40px;
     line-height: 60px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #f3f2f1;
    }
    .navegacion_hijo ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #f3f2f1;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <header>
  <div class="contenedor">
   <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="menu()"></i></div>
    <div class="logo">
     <h3>Guardian</h3>
    </div>
   </div>    
   <nav class="navegacion" id="navegacion">
    <div class="navegacion_hijo">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home fa-lg" id="iconos"></i>junex10</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users fa-lg" id="iconos"></i>Documentacion</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-lg" id="iconos"></i>Proyectos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg" id="iconos"></i>Contacto</a></li>    
    </ul>
   </div>
   </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Agrega tu codigo para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: versión de fontawesome? arriba o abajo de qué elemento?

Comment: 5.0.13 es la version

Comment: Creo que era font awesome (o puede que Bootstrap) que tiene sus propias clases para esto. Voy a mirar y lo confirmo.

Answer (score 1):

para ponerlo a la derecha del texto: lo definís a la derecha del texto.

para ponerlo arriba del texto: insertas un salto de línea (line break) justo después del icono.

para ponerlo debajo del texto: lo definís a la derecha del texto e insertas un salto de línea (line break) justo antes del icono.

vas a tener que arreglar los `line-height` del css, y tal vez un `text-center` para los arriba/abajo de, o un `display:block;margin:0 auto;` todo depende de cómo quieras que se vea.

```css
*, *::after, *::before{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
body header{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    background: #363636;
}
body header .contenedor{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
header .logo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
header .logo h3{
    color: #f3f2f1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
header .menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-end;
}
header .menu i{
    color: #f3f2f1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header .navegacion{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 1300px;
}
header .navegacion_hijo{
    position: absolute;
    background: #363636;
    padding: 40px;
}
.navegacion_hijo ul li{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #f3f2f1;
}
.navegacion_hijo ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f3f2f1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="menu"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" onclick="menu()"></i></div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h3>Guardian</h3>
            </div>
        </div>              
        <nav class="navegacion" id="navegacion">
            <div class="navegacion_hijo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">junex10 <i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users fa-lg"></i> Documentacion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proyectos<br/><i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i><br/>Contacto</a></li>              
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Gracias ya logre moverlos